# Get total width of JSX Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could I get the width of a JSX.Element? If I was in vanilla, I would do something like

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');
document.body.appendChild(button)
window.getComputedStyle(button).width
```

Now I need to do the same, but it seems `ref` is null and I'm not sure even how to temporarily append to the DOM just to see what its width would be.

```
const button: JSX.Element = <CustomButton/>;
/// ....
```

Comment: This smells like a _possible_ XY issue-- what is the reason you need the width of the JSX element?  Not to say there is _no_ valid case for doing so, but _most_ of the time sniffing on the DOM in React is an antipattern (or antipattern adjacent).

Comment: Basically I need the width to know what the max # of buttons in a div can be. If the width of the button is 100px for example, and the div is 500px, then we can only have 5.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to check and consider.

1. where is the ref created and does it get forwarded correctly to a
   valid dom element (make sure that CustomButton uses forwardRef).
2. you don't need to append anything in react to look at the width. all you need is ref.current.clientWidth or ref.current.getBoundingClientRect(), but ref.current has to exist in the first place :-)
3. if you need access to the ref.current element when your component first mounts (and not in a onClick or some other callback - then this does not apply)  you'll have to use useLayoutEffect as the javascript runs before the dom is rendered so there is technically no  to measure yet.

See this example:

### ParentComponent.tsx

```js
import {useState, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState<number | null>(null);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if(ref?.current && !width) {
            const { clientWidth } = ref.current;
            setWidth(clientWidth);
        }
    }, [ref?.current]);
    
   console.log('width', width);

// `width` will be null at first render,
// then when CustomButton renders and <button> is created the ref will be 
// updated, triggering your layout side effect that saves the 
// clientWidth to the state. State change will trigger a rerender of 
// ParentComponent and your console.log will finally print the width (whose
// value is stored in the state).

    return <CustomButton ref={ref}/>;
};
```

### CustomButton.tsx

```js
import {forwardRef} from 'react';

const CustomButton = forwarRef((props, ref) => {

    return (
        <>
        // some other stuff
        <button ref={ref}/>>Click</button>
        </>
     );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is to use a ref, and then observe it within an effect, which is called after the DOM gets rendered:

```js
const ref = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(ref.current).width)
}, []);
return <button ref={ref}/>;
```

Comment: This code will break for 2 reasons: 1- The first (and only) time this useEffect runs the ref will be empty. To fix this add ref?.current to the deps array. 2- the right syntax is window.getComputedStyle(ref.current).

Comment: You're right about (2) the missing `.current` -- now fixed above. Regarding (1), the `useEffect` callback gets called *after* the first DOM render, so `ref.current` will actually always be set in this context.